# Create a triangular appendix under div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have received a design from my designer and I was wondering if this is even possible using HTML, CSS or JavaScript?

[image: Triangle one]

This seems to be possible using CSS and create a seperate div under the main div with position absolute.

However, if I use a background image on the div, the designer wants it to look as following:
[image: Triangle two]

I honestly have no idea how to to search for a solution for this, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use css triangles and rotate with background color as required https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick little thing for the css triangle - you can adjust to suit:

```css
.createdDiv{
  height:100px;
  margin-top:10px;
  background:#ddd;
}

.createdDiv:before{
    content: "";
    border-top: 15px solid white;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right:-10px;
    z-index:99;
}
```

```html
<div class='createdDiv'></div>
```

Comment: Ahhh, came 10s too late to answer !

Comment: He he - @AymDev its a race in here with these answers :)

Comment: and I like to take it as a friendly one ;)

Comment: This is a white arrow - how will the op get the image he wants in the arrow?

Comment: @Pete - working on that now

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! Pete indeed found a post that asks exactly what I am asking, but I gave you a plus 1 for the effort :)